# Como Inserir Código html dentro do Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, funções

Possuo este código, gostaria de saber se ele está correto da forma em que está?

Código JavaScript:

```
function texto(){
    if(SONome == 'Windows 10 x32'){
    window.location.href = 
'http://teccitystore.com.br/downloads/eCHEF_Install.exe';
      var a_ = '<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-small wsite-button-
highlight"></a>';
      document.html(a);
    } else if(SONome == 'Windows 10 x64'){
      window.location.href="http://teccitystore.com.br/downloads/eCHEF_Install_x64.exe
";
      var a_ = '<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-small wsite-button-
highlight"></a>';
      document.html(a);
    }
```

Código html:

```
<a class="wsite-button-inner"  ng-disabled="boxes.email" id="Win32" 
name="Win32" onclick="texto()">
Windows x32
</a>
```

Comment: Não seria melhor dar a opção da pessoa escolher se deseja instalar o 32bit ou 64bit? Isso porque existem muitas situações aonde mesmo a maior parte dos sistemas operacionais sendo 64bit e ainda sim o usuário preferir usar 32bit (x86).

Comment: Concordo com com seu ponto de vista @GuilhermeNascimento porém possuo um superior que pediu conforme a escolha acima, não posso ir contra entende..

Comment: Entendo sim Alis, ainda sim penso que para quase tudo é possivel apresentar argumentos e até exemplos de sites grandes que o fazem, todavia voltando ao seu problema, poderia me dizer que função é esta `document.html()`? Foi você quem a criou, ela não é padrão creio eu, aonde exatamente pretende injetar o link `<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-small wsite-button-
highlight"></a>` na página? PS: não fui eu quem negativou a pergunta.

Comment: nesta parte havia pedido ajuda a um amigo, mas não resolveu muito, olha, na pagina logo quando ela é carregada é informado por outra função qual seu Windows, e era para esta função ai pegar o valor do windows da pessoa que esta em "SONome", e dividir entre os dois possíveis casos. Caso seja Wx64 iria chamar o arquivo de download,e a class do botão para deixa-lo azul. Deveria acontecer mais ou menos isso nos dois casos.Injetarei no código html, na parte em que postei, este era o esperado ao chamar a função que a contia

Comment: Então a unica necessidade é iniciar o download automaticamente ao clicar em `<a class="wsite-button-inner"`, correto? Então qual a utilidade de `<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-small wsite-button- highlight">` e `<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-small wsite-button-
highlight"></a>`? Pois se eles não tiverem utilidade alguma irei sugerir alguma mudanças em teu código. Por favor explique exatamente o que deseja que o teu código faça.

Comment: Basicamente: Caso a variável seja um caso, é para começar o download. Objetivo principal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode utilizar a propriedade no elemento de innnerHTML = ou += e meter o codigo de html

Comment: poderia explicar de uma forma mais detalhada se possível?

Comment: Então se tu quer acrescentar por exemplo um dom element <a> num certo id eu vou demonstrar . document.getElementById("main-content").innerHTML += "<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-small wsite-button- highlight"></a>"; Isto irá acrescentar o que já tinha antes e + este novo conteudo de html á tag main-content, isto é só um exemplo. Eu prefiro jQuery onde tu pode fazer mais rapido isto, por exemplo em vez de procurar elementbyid faz so $('#main-content").html("<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-small wsite-button- highlight"></a>");, mas isso vai ser consigo.